# why google doesn't update my updated posts?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

Recently I updated some posts from website and change seo yoast title that should change the title on the google search result. But after a while the title is the old one and didn't update!!!

Answer (score 1):

first, go to the webmaster tool and ask Google to re-index page/post in the URL inspection area it will take 1 hour to a week depending on your website domain authority.
If you made a lot of changes you can just re-submit your sitemap.
that what I have for you, good luck

Comment: thanks.can you tell me how can I re-submit the sitemap?! there is no option for that in new google search console

Comment: when I use URL inspection for a post there is this message : Indexed but not submit on google!!
Also when I want to Test URL Live there is this message : URL is available to Google, but has issues
If it gets indexed and selected as canonical, it could appear in Google Search results. However, some issues prevent it from being eligible for all enhancements.